# Did Chewbacca hold back and miss on purpose?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, kylo-ren, chewbacca

So today I passed by a small comic showing how Chewie was there since

> Kylo Ren was born and how he witnessed the transition in the kid's life.

The comic made it as if that was a flashback to the moment Chewie was about to shoot his bowcaster.

> [image: Tyson Murphy's comic]

Back when I saw the scene, I thought given the distance and the blaster powerful shot, Chewie could've easily missed his shot, however, after taking into account this perspective, it might be possible that Chewie only intended to injure him. 
Is there any other proof that Chewie might've held back ?

PS: Comic source is [Tyson Murphy](http://tysonmurphy.tumblr.com/post/136936953919/star-wars-7-spoilers-a-quick-little-comic-i)

Comment: @yondamine008 Apart from this little comic, do you have any reason to believe Chewie would hold back? Like if his life-dept to Han would affect the situation in any way?

Comment: This is exactly what I am asking for in this question. I don't have any, and till I saw this, I thought it was due to the distance + the crossbow blaster powerful recoil that Chewie only managed to wound him. This is why I am asking if there's any evidence that Chewie might've spared Kylo on purpose.

Comment: As an aside, I didn't ask for these feels today...

Comment: @GabeWillard www.FeelsBadMan.com

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## He decided not to shoot again

Perhaps Chewie did spare Kylo.  Whether or not he intentionally botched the first shot, once Kylo was on his knees in pain on the catwalk, Chewie could have fired another bolt to finish the job, but didn't.

It's true that the first shot provoked instant return fire from the nearby stormtroopers.  From the novelization:

> Hostile fire being something the group of stormtroopers could react to without having to wait for an order, they immediately blasted back at Chewie.

This may have prevented Chewie from taking another shot, but Chewie has been in worse situations and I feel he could have had a second shot if he wanted one, especially given Kylo's very vulnerable position.

## Peter Mayhew tweet

There are no direct official statements on the matter.

However, after the comic was published, Chewbacca actor Peter Mayhew replied to it on Twitter:

> **In case it hadn't crossed your mind.** @starwars @TheWookieeRoars @KyloR3n #TheForceAwakens pic.twitter.com/8wjHeD6h0l
>
> Peter Mayhew (@TheWookieeRoars) January 9, 2016

While not a direct confirmation of Tyson Murphy's interpretation of the scene, it does suggest that Mayhew had given it prior thought and it may have been at least a point of discussion during the filming of the scene.

Apart from these observations, there is no other evidence that he held back.

Comment: +1 for the tweet. This adds a whole new dimension to the movie's plot.

Comment: @yondaime008 : Thanks.  I agree!

Comment: Not an answer, but I think in the end the first shot didn't hold back Wookies are quick to anger, and Chewie appears to be shooting on reflex. After firing that shot though, that's when he cleared up from the bloodrage a bit and held back from a second shot after remembering who that is.

Comment: In legends canon, Chewies life debt extended to Hans family... if this was the case here it would have been a factor. No evidence but it always made perfect sense to me that Chewie would extend the same protection to Hans family.